# Laravel - How to pass parameter from controller to route and use it in another controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I have configured a resource route as below

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

When a user posts data, it will call the store method in the controller where it will add the data and set a message for success/failure.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // return $request;
    $request->validate(
        [
            "firstName" => 'required',
            "lastName" => 'required',
            "phoneNo" => 'required',
            "email" => 'email:rfc,dns'
        ]
    );

    $date = date(now());
    $data = [
        'firstName' => $request->firstName,
        'lastName' => $request->lastName,
        'phoneNo' => $request->phoneNo,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'designation' => $request->designation,
        'status' => $request->status,
        'createdAt' => $date,
        'updatedAt' => $date,
    ];
    $user = Firebase::insertData($data, static::$collection);
    if ($user->id() != null) {
        $message = "User Created Successfully";
    } else {
        $message = "Something went wrong. Please contact System Admin with error code USR001";
    }
    return redirect()->route('users.index', ['message' => $message]);
}
```

This will redirect to the index method of the same controller. How can I use the $message parameter in the index method and send it to the view? My index method is below

```
public function index()
{
    $userCollection = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('users');
    $userData = $userCollection->documents();
    $response = [];
    $app = app();
    foreach ($userData as $data) {
        $user = $app->make('stdClass');
        $user->firstName = $data["firstName"];
        $user->lastName = $data["lastName"];
        $user->phoneNo = $data["phoneNo"];
        $user->email = $data["email"];
        $user->designation = $data["designation"];
        $user->status = $data["status"];
        $user->createdAt = $data["createdAt"];
        $user->updatedAt = $data["updatedAt"];
        array_push($response, $user);
    }
    return view('pages.user.list-user', ['response' => $response]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass the message as a flash message using the `with()` method with the redirect method.

Edit your redirect code as:

```
return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('message', $message]);
```

and add the below code in your `pages.user.list-user` blade file:

```
@if (session('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Visit https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data for more info on redirects with a flash message.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your redirect code :

```
return redirect()->route('users.index', ['message' => $message]);
```

with

```
return view('pages.user.list-user', ['message' => $message]);
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) First of all, pass the message in the parameter of index function:

```
public function index($message)
{
...
}
```

(2) This is okay, you wrote correctly:

```
return redirect()->route('users.index', ['message' => $message]);
```

(3) Now just access the message in the view (blade) and print it:

```
{{ $message }}
```

You can also store message in $response array and simply pass the $response to the desired view:

```
$response['message'] = $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the index method like if the parameter used in the controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   // Your code
   $message = $request['message'];
}
```

If you want to access the message in view use

```
return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('message', $message]);
```

and access from the view using `session('message')` like in OMi Shah's answer